# How do I update Drupal 7 to Drupal 7 DEV via Drush command line?

Tags: 7, drush

I have an old drupal 7 installation and I would like to update this via drush. Usually I download the drupal 7 dev version through the website using wget and untar it into the public_html directory and overwrite everything.

I know i can update drupal modules via "drush dl " but not sure how to do it for core easily using drush.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drush dl` is for downloading modules the first time, not updating.

To update core to dev version:

`drush up drupal-7.x-dev`

Comment: ok just did that shows that my drupal version is already -dev, but it doesnt update it to the latest dev. how can that be done?

Comment: hmm it should. you can try also `drush up drupal-7.x` without the `-dev`, but I think it should behave the same. Are you sure it's not updating to the latest dev version?